# ビジネスプロセス管理(BPM)プラットフォームActivitiにて、プロセスの実行担当者の変更～完了までをREST APIで実現する方法

Tags: java, spring

## 実現したいこと

オープンソースのビジネスプロセス管理(BPM)プラットフォームActivitiにて
プロセスの実行担当者の変更～完了までをREST APIで実現する方法を教えてください。

## 試したこと

#### 試したこと1

1. プロセスインスタンスの作成
   restの「POST runtime/process-instances」を実行。
2. 担当者の変更(act_ru_taskテーブルのassignee_カラムの変更)
   restの「POST runtime/tasks/{taskId} 」でrequestbodyのaction属性にdelegateを指定、assignee属性に「1」のプロセスインスタンス作成時を実行した際のユーザを設定して実行。
   act_ru_taskテーブルのassignee_カラムの値が変更されることを確認。
3. タスクの完了
   restの「POST runtime/tasks/{taskId} 」でrequestbodyのaction属性にcompleteを指定して実行。
   response code=500で「A delegated task cannot be completed, but should be resolved instead.」とエラーになる。

#### 試したこと2

1. プロセスインスタンスの作成
   restの「POST runtime/process-instances」を実行。
2. 担当者の変更(act_ru_taskテーブルのassignee_カラムの変更)
   restの「POST runtime/tasks/{taskId} 」でrequestbodyのaction属性にdelegateを指定、assignee属性に「1」のプロセスインスタンス作成時を実行した際のユーザを設定して実行。
   act_ru_taskテーブルのassignee_カラムの値が変更されることを確認。
3. 解決を実行
   restの「POST runtime/tasks/{taskId} 」でrequestbodyのaction属性にresolveを指定して実行。
   act_ru_taskテーブルのassignee_カラムの値が「2」の変更前の値に戻ってしまうことを確認。